# Can't use pool.map for a class method in ROS Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, ros

I have a time-consuming function which is called many times with different input arguments. I am trying to parallelize it by using the `Pool` from the `multiprocessing` module in Python 3. Please see a sample code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
import actionlib
import multiprocessing as mp
from actionlib_tutorials.msg import FibonacciAction, FibonacciResult


def time_taking_task(n):
    # only for debugging
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a


class FibonacciActionClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(
            name,
            FibonacciAction,
            execute_cb=self.cb,
            auto_start=False,
        )
        self._as.start()

    def time_taking_task(self, n):
        # only for debugging
        a, b = 0, 1
        for _ in range(0, n):
            a, b = b, a + b
        return a

    def cb(self, goal):
        result = FibonacciResult()
        result.sequence.append(0)
        with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
            nums = pool.map(self.time_taking_task, list(range(1, goal.order + 1)))  # doesn't work
            # nums = pool.map(time_taking_task, list(range(1, goal.order + 1))) # works
        result.sequence.extend(nums)
        self._as.set_succeeded(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node("fibonacci")
    server = FibonacciActionClass(rospy.get_name())
    rospy.spin()
```

The `map` method takes a function and an iterable object. Giving `time_taking_task` as function works but `self.time_taking_task` throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1643875827.675670]: Exception in your execute callback: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/actionlib/simple_action_server.py", line 289, in executeLoop
    self.execute_callback(goal)
  File "/home/user/ros_ws/src/actionlib_tutorials/scripts/fibonacci_server.py", line 34, in cb
    nums = pool.map(self.time_taking_task, list(range(1, goal.order + 1)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

I believe ROS isn't allowing the Pool somehow. Any workaround, please?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a function in a python mutliprocessing subprocess, the function and all its arguments must be pickable. As `self` is one of the arguments for the function you are passing to the pool, your class seems to be not pickable. This seems to be due to `actionlib.SimpleActionServer` nit being pickable due to the RLock object. See this [website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) for what types are pickable by default.

You could either try using another library like [pathos](https://pathos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pathos.html) instead of multiprocessing, as it uses a different way of pickling objects. Or, you could try to move your function out of your class and pass data that resides in your class and that has to be used by the function as function arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion. I thought already to re-structure as you said by moving the function out of the class. But the whole point of having an ActionServer was just because of this `time_taking_task`. I tried `joblib` module too but it throws a similar lock error.